# How do I output WebGrid column data with line breaks?

Tags: sql, webmatrix, webgrid

I followed the ASP.Net tutorial for the WebPages Platform using Razor coding with WebMatrix and now I would like to add to it. I added a textarea to capture the data for a "review" element and store it in the database. But when I pull the "review" data from the database it does not retain it's original formatting it's just a long one-liner. Here is the code I'm working with.

```
        @grid.GetHtml(
            tableStyle: "grid",
            headerStyle: "head",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(format: @<a href="~/EditMovie?id=@item.ID">Edit</a>),
                grid.Column("Title"),
                grid.Column("Genre"),
                grid.Column("Year"),
                grid.Column("Review"),
                grid.Column(format: @<a href="~/DeleteMovie?id=@item.ID">Delete</a>)
            )
```

How can I make WebGrid include the line breaks, tabs, white space...? I think I should use format but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer myself.
Here's how I resolved this:

```
    <div>
        @grid.GetHtml(
            tableStyle: "grid",
            headerStyle: "head",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(format: @<a href="~/EditMovie?id=@item.ID">Edit</a>),
                grid.Column("Title"),
                grid.Column("Genre"),
                grid.Column("Year"),
                grid.Column("Review", format: (item) => 
                {
                   string review = item.Review ?? "";
                   return new HtmlString(review.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>"));
                }),
                grid.Column(format: @<a href="~/DeleteMovie?id=@item.ID">Delete</a>)
            )
        )
    </div>
```

In webgrid, the line breaks needs to be replaced with `<br/>`.